# how to receive a push notification on IOS react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I'm trying to used the rest API of firebase with react native. I'm trying to used the notification request but my fetch doesn't work .

I have an error like that :

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 10):
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

i also console.log the response i get this :
{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "1223679F-6B8F-4104-9085-060585EDF71E", "name": "1.1", "offset": 0, "size": 0, "type": "text/html"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "1223679F-6B8F-4104-9085-060585EDF71E", "name": "1.1", "offset": 0, "size": 0, "type": "text/html"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"alt-svc": "h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"", "content-length": "0", "content-type": "text/html", "date": "Tue, 06 Apr 2021 14:20:39 GMT", "server": "scaffolding on HTTPServer2", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x-xss-protection": "0"}}, "ok": false, "status": 404, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send%20HTTP/1.1"}

this is my fetch and i call him on the componentdidmount of my app.js

```
Notif = async () => {
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + (await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')),
      
      message:{
        token:"ff_Zolz1s0mmgrovad27JG:APA91bHlV5bAXyNHI3aWGyjltdgmJP8mmGBlEC0mPBA72IIJGqoliH4gm1rCQp0szQ5JypKxNhcWcKb7JrOwUTZDmaCB02y4dS553WVDdsxbWuLeK7cqoMjTRjFtFfdMb8bVGxO65BTq",
        notification:{
          body:"This is an FCM notification message!",
          title:"FCM Message"
        }
     }
     
    });
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
    };

    fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1', options)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        },
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are handling the fetch request incorrectly as it is missing a catch clause. Secondly, check the url you are sending in the request as it seems to not be properly formatted as a string.

Side note you could await the fetch function since you already made the Notfi function asynchronous and surround this with a try/catch block.